# How to generate lagged variable for unbalanced panel in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

For unbalanced panel data, it's hard for me to generate lagged variable, especially the lagged length is more than 2. For example, I have a dataset that is a unbalanced panel data. The objective of the task is to generate a lagged 2-month variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

a=[[1,'1990/1/1',1],
[1,'1990/2/1',2],
[1,'1990/3/1',3],
[2,'1989/12/1',3],
[2,'1990/1/1',3],
[2,'1990/2/1',4],
[2,'1990/3/1',5.5],
[2,'1990/4/1',5],
[2,'1990/6/1',6]]

data=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['id','date','value'])
data['date']=pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

Currently, My solution is

```
data['lag2value']=np.where((data.groupby('id')['date'].diff(2)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).fillna(0).round()==2,
        data.sort_values(['id','date']).groupby('id')['value'].shift(2),np.nan)
```

However, for the last obs, it does have a lagged two-month observation, that's to say the date `1990-6-1` corresponds to the `1990-4-1`. My codes cannot figure it out.

```
   id       date  value  lag2value
0   1 1990-01-01    1.0        NaN
1   1 1990-02-01    2.0        NaN
2   1 1990-03-01    3.0        1.0
3   2 1989-12-01    3.0        NaN
4   2 1990-01-01    3.0        NaN
5   2 1990-02-01    4.0        3.0
6   2 1990-03-01    5.5        3.0
7   2 1990-04-01    5.0        4.0
8   2 1990-06-01    6.0        NaN
```

One possible solution is to build a complete date table that is a balanced panel dataset, and merge the current table to it. However, if the working data is large, it's time-comsuming to work on the complete table.

I want to know any elegent solution to the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can a single `id` contain repeated dates?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma，no repeared dates, but dates with gaps.

Comment: Does the dates always start from monthly start frequency?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma，Yes. Even it doesn't start from the first day, we can generate a fake month date. The key point is that there is only one month within a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use:**

```
val = df.set_index('date').groupby('id').resample('MS').asfreq()['value']
val  = val.groupby(level=0).shift(2) 
df['lag2val'] = df.set_index(['id', 'date']).index.map(val)
```

**Details:**

STEP A: Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `id` and use [`groupby.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) to resample the grouped frame using monthly start frequency.

```
print(val)
id  date      
1   1990-01-01    1.0
    1990-02-01    2.0
    1990-03-01    3.0
2   1989-12-01    3.0
    1990-01-01    3.0
    1990-02-01    4.0
    1990-03-01    5.5
    1990-04-01    5.0
    1990-05-01    NaN
    1990-06-01    6.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

STEP B: Use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on `level=0` to group the series `val` and `shift` 2 periods down to create a lagged `2` months `val` series.

```
print(val)
id  date      
1   1990-01-01    NaN
    1990-02-01    NaN
    1990-03-01    1.0
2   1989-12-01    NaN
    1990-01-01    NaN
    1990-02-01    3.0
    1990-03-01    3.0
    1990-04-01    4.0
    1990-05-01    5.5
    1990-06-01    5.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

STEP C: Finally, use `set_index` along with [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the new lagged `val` series to the orginal dataframe `df`.

```
print(df)
   id       date  value  lag2val
0   1 1990-01-01    1.0      NaN
1   1 1990-02-01    2.0      NaN
2   1 1990-03-01    3.0      1.0
3   2 1989-12-01    3.0      NaN
4   2 1990-01-01    3.0      NaN
5   2 1990-02-01    4.0      3.0
6   2 1990-03-01    5.5      3.0
7   2 1990-04-01    5.0      4.0
8   2 1990-06-01    6.0      5.0
```